# shower head has running water when off but another faucet is turned on

Tags: plumbing, shower, leak, plumbing-fixture

The shower in our first floor bathroom will flow water out of it when the bath tub faucet on the second floor is running or the washing machine on the second floor is filling. The water is cold. This shower doesn't drip or leak unless one of the two mentioned fixtures are running.

Comment: All I can offer is a joke:  "My feet smell and my nose runs" so the doctor says, "you're built upside down"    Seriously, though, this site has many super plumbers who can probably give an assist on this one.

Comment: You’re going to need to give us information and/or picture of the shower valve.  The control, not the head.  How old is the valve? Has it always done this, or did it just start?  How much water comes out a dribble? Full flow?